# How can I use a pipe in a while condition?

Tags: bash, scripts, pipe

I want to loop while grep does or does not find something I can write:

```
while grep 'matches' inLogFile.txt
do
  echo good.
  sleep 10
done
```

Or

```
while grep -v 'notHereYet' inLogFile.txt
do
  sleep 2
done
echo -e '\a'Yo! It is here now.
```

I'm typing these at the interactive shell prompt.

So I wanted to repeatedly check `df` for when a volume actually got mounted, kind of like:

```
while df | grep -v '/toBeMounted'
do
  sleep 2
done
echo -e '\a'Hey, I think you wanted to know that /toBeMounted is available finally.
```

I'm having trouble figuring out how to group the pipe into the condition.

I know I could do something like:

```
while [ -z "$(df|grep '/toBeMounted')" ]
do
  sleep 2
done
echo -e '\a'Okay that is finally present now.
```

Yet I feel as though there should be a way to do it using exit values instead of the string comparison.

Comment: adding `-q` will allow grep to exit with a status instead, which is more suitable for statements

Comment: Thanks @bac0n `-q` makes even more sense in this case.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To get the logic right, just minor changes are required.  Use:

```
while ! df | grep '/toBeMounted'
do
  sleep 2
done
echo -e '\a'Hey, I think you wanted to know that /toBeMounted is available finally.
```

#### Discussion

The corresponding code in the question was:

```
while df | grep -v '/toBeMounted'
```

The exit code of a pipeline is the exit code of the last command in the pipeline.  `grep -v '/toBeMounted'` will return true (code=0) if at least one line of input does not match `/toBeMounted`.  Thus, this tests whether there are other things mounted besides `/toBeMounted`.  *This is not at all what you are looking for.*

To use `df` and `grep` to test whether `/toBeMounted` is mounted, we need

```
df | grep '/toBeMounted'
```

This returns true if `/toBeMounted` is mounted.  What you actually need is the negation of this: you need a condition that is true if  `/toBeMounted` is not mounted.  To do that, we just need to use negation, denoted by `!`:

```
! df | grep '/toBeMounted'
```

And, this is what we use in the code above.

#### Documentation

From [the Bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pipelines):

> The return status of a pipeline is the exit status of the last 
>   command,  unless  the  pipefail  option  is  enabled.  If pipefail is
>   enabled, the pipeline's return status is the value of the last
>   (rightmost) command to exit with a non-zero status, or zero if all
>   commands exit successfully.  If the reserved  word  `!`   precedes  a
>   pipeline, the exit status of that pipeline is the logical negation of
>   the exit status as described  above.  The shell waits for all commands
>   in the pipeline to terminate before returning a value.

Comment: Yeah it looks like my real problem wasn't the pipe, but not clearly thinking about the `-v` on a line by line basis.

Comment: @dlamblin Yes, it is a subtle point.  `-v` negates the `grep` test but, for multi-line output, that is  _not_ the same as a negation of the `grep` exit code.

Answer (score 4):

The fact that you're using `df` with `grep` tells me that you're filtering output of `df` until some device mounts to specific directory, i.e. whether or not it's on the list.

Instead of filtering the list focus on the directory that you want. Luckly for us, the utility `mountpoint` allows us to do exactly that, and allows to deal with exit status of that command. Consider this:

```
$ mountpoint  /mnt/HDD/                                                        
/mnt/HDD/ is a mountpoint
$ echo $?
0
$ mountpoint  ~                                                                
/home/xieerqi is not a mountpoint
$ echo $?
1
```

Your script thus, can be rewritten as

```
while ! mountput /toBeMounted > /dev/null
do
   sleep 3
done
echo "Yup, /toBeMounted got mounted!"
```

Sample run with my own disk:

```
$ while ! mountpoint /mnt/HDD > /dev/null
> do 
>     echo "Waiting"
>     sleep 1
> done && echo "/mnt/HDD is mounted"
Waiting
Waiting
Waiting
Waiting
Waiting
/mnt/HDD is mounted
```

On a side note, you can fairly easy implement your own version of `mountpoint` command, for instance , in python , like i did:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from os import path
import sys

def main():

    if not sys.argv[1]:
       print('Missing a path')
       sys.exit(1)

    full_path = path.realpath(sys.argv[1])
    with open('/proc/self/mounts') as mounts:
       print
       for line in mounts:
           if full_path in line:
              print(full_path,' is mountpoint')
              sys.exit(0)
    print(full_path,' is not a mountpoint')
    sys.exit(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Sample run:

```
$ python3 ./is_mountpoint.py /mnt/HDD                                          
/mnt/HDD  is mountpoint
$ python3 ./is_mountpoint.py ~                                                 
/home/xieerqi  is not a mountpoint
```

Comment: I was generally unclear on using a pipe in a conditional statement. But the specific case of checking for a mounted device, `mountpoint` sounds perfect, thanks. Though conceptually in this case I could have also just done: `while [ ! -d /toBeMounted ]; do sleep 2; done; echo -e \\aDing the directory is available now.`

Comment: @dlamblin well , `[ ! -d /toBeMounted ]` tells me that you're expecting that directory to be created, though that is not usually how mounting works. Sometimes a sysadmin has dedicated directory where stuff is mounted, so that directory is already created. I mean, it really depends on what you're looking for. With `mountpoint` it's better because you have simple syntax and it works for either created directory case or to-be created case. As for pipes in conditional statements, they're messy , so I'd recommend avoiding them , since the exit status of last piped command is not always what we want

Comment: oh, right, I'd need to look for a sub-directory I know to be on the drive but not at the mount point. like `[ ! -d /toBeMounted/stuff ]` where as mountpoint can tell if a directory currently has something mounted on it, I suppose.